# Find number of rows where both values are 0

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to figure out the number of rows that have `col1 != 0 || col2 != 0`

sample:

```
> head(df2$col1)
[1] 3 0 2 1 0 5
> head(df2$col2)
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

What I tried:

```
>dim(df2)
[1] 38272    69
> jj = df2[df2$col1 != 0 || df2$col2 != 0]
> dim(jj)
[1] 38272    69
```

Not sure why the dimensions are the same even though you can clearly see from the `head()` that there is an example where `col1` and `col2` is 0

Comment: `df2[df2$col1 == 0 & df2$col2 == 0, ]` based on your title.

Comment: @www yup that was it. Thanks! Will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df2$col1 != 0 || df2$col2 != 0` matches everything because it reads as **col1 is not 0 OR col2 is not 0**. If you want to find **col1 is 0 AND col2 is 0**, please use the following.

```
df2 <- data.frame(col1 = c(3, 0, 2, 1, 0, 5),
                  col2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))

df2[df2$col1 == 0 & df2$col2 == 0, ]
  col1 col2
2    0    0
5    0    0

nrow(df2[df2$col1 == 0 & df2$col2 == 0, ])
# [1] 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to study the dplyr package documentation:

```
library(dplyr)

new_dff <- df2 %>%
         filter(col1==0, col2==0)
```